# how can i add image,js and dll to my project

Tags: web-part

I am new in sharepoint development, i want to make wsp with:
1)image
2)javascript/jquery 
3) dll

suppose theses all are in within project. so tell me how can i add image,js and dll to my project and deploy as farm solution in sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will usually locate those physical files under a mapped folder called "Layouts", that maps to the 14 hive.

Here's a pretty detailed step-by-step guide on how to use this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2010/03/12/deploying-files-using-mapped-folders.aspx

Hope it helps.

[UPDATE]

For DLL dependencies: In Visual Studio Double Click on "Package" -> Go to "Advanced" tab -> You can add either project references or external dependencies (such as AjaxControlToolkit)

Comment: thanks for reply, i read it. so i have to add mapped folder for assembly also like:
 ~/_layouts/Template/UserCode/assemblies/SharePointProject1/AjaxControlToolkit.dll..

can you please tell me how can i add js file? i couldn't found script folder

Comment: . JS files can be added in another folder under the _layouts folder (such as (Layouts/MyProject/Scripts)
. Updated the answer with details for DLL's

Answer (score 1):

The way you deploy artifacts depends on the type of solution you intend, and of course other considerations linked to architecture of your solution and intended use (single time, or reusable artifacts):
- when considering farm solutions, indeed _layouts could be an option - available across all site collections/web apps/farm. Always you need to consider name clashes - many features could deploy same files in the same location (e.g. jQuery libraries - very common scenario). Try thinking folders hierarchy appropriately, in accordance with governance policies (if any)
 - for Sandbox - you cannot deploy physically in _layouts or _controltemplates, etc. - there you should rather use Module to deploy files. These go into the Content database finally. (example http://wedontneedadebugger.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/deploying-jquery-libraries-as-a-sandbox-solution/)

You need to consider where effectively you deploy also by looking at the type of your web template (only Publishing sites have Style library and site collection level Images libraries, etc., Collaboration sites usually use the Site Assets library). Do you plan to use these in a master page? Again, consider where it shall be deployed and security requirements - you do not want to deploy an image and when used in your web-part - it doesn't show to everyone (rule: use the Least privileged principle when you test!)

These are just few thoughts, but at least to get you started.